# Access CSS Classes specified in Menu options

Tags: menus

Is there a way to access CSS styles specified in the Menu CSS options in the code?

I would like to access the names of the css classes ([as shown here](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/customizing-the-wordpress-menu-with-custom-classes/)) in my php page.

How would I do it?

Comment: u want to add a custom class to your menu?

Comment: No. I want to be able to get (in php code) the css class names ONCE i've added in Menu configuration screen.

Comment: did u tried the javascript .innerhtml ?

Comment: I think you missunderstood the question. I'm asking: in php how can I access CSS property of the wordpress MENU that you specify in the "edit menu item" page

Comment: If you are after what I think you are after, you would have to use the nav_menu_css_class filter or create a custom nav menu Walker.